# Зарою я пфенниг на даче. Пусть(,) на фиг(,) растёт он в цене

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

> Зарою я пфенниг на даче. Пусть(,) на фиг(,) растёт он в цене.

Comment: А что если это только слышится «веник», а на самом деле поется «пфенниг» или «фенинг»? Пфе́нниг (нем. Pfennig) — немецкая (германская[1]) денежная единица.

Comment: Точно! https://ok.ru/video/226824553823  Михаил Боярский: "Гей-Бизнесмен"  1989
Хронически не было денег
Но тут как всегда, повезло
Нашёл у гостинницы пфенинг... 

... и понеслось!

Comment: https://dzen.ru/a/YD1ZzWu6yDfN4KNb  Но в венике тоже что-то есть. Что-то современное...  Пфенинг превратился в веник, и никто в этом не сомневается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Зарою я пфенниг на даче. Пусть, **на фиг,** растёт он в цене.*

Имеется в виду: *Пусть, **ну его на фиг**, растёт он в цене.*

Это **вставка**, авторская реплика.

Comment: Но он же *феник* говорит!

Comment: Это он рисуется, по всему же видно. Понравиться хочет.  Феник у него      иностранный.

Comment: Что такое *феник*-то?

Comment: А что это такое, расскажите?  У меня был текст с веником, а не феником?

Comment: Для справок.  Буква Ф в русском языке встречается преимущественно в заимствованных словах, так как в древнерусском языке не было соответствующего звука Ф, который появился только после падения редуцированных гласных, например: въход – в(ф)ход.
Буква Ф заимствована из греческой алфавита при создании  письменности при Кирилле и Мефодии. Еще двести лет назад слова с этой буквой не часто встречались в русском языке, но сейчас появилось и русифицировалось много таких корней. Тем не менее, буква Ф по-прежнему остается самой редкой.

Comment: Песню Боярского послушайте — «Бизнесмен».

Comment: Да слушала я его. Все слова коверкает, на иностранный лад.  Произносит: фенник. Почему?