# Почему пфенниг превратился в веник?

Tags: лексика, семантика, орфоэпия, перенос

Действительно, в известной **песне Боярского** 90-х годов прошлого века в текстовом варианте был ***пфенниг***, но вот в 20-х годах нашего века он стал ***"веником"***. И никто в Интернете в этом **не сомневается.**

**А почему?** Ведь с веником смысл песни **не очень ясен**, да и времени прошло не так уж много. Но сомнений нет практически **ни у кого**. **Странная история**, разные мысли...

Жизнь изменилась, мы изменились, мы стали другими?  **И готовы пфенниг считать веником?**

**[Песня Боярского](https://dzen.ru/a/YD1ZzWu6yDfN4KNb)**  **[Видео](https://ok.ru/video/226824553823)**

**[Тема](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476446/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5)** обсуждалась на форуме.

**ПФЕННИГ**, -а; м. [нем. Pfennig] В Германии: мелкая монета, одна сотая часть марки.

Comment: Ах, Шарон, ну зачем, у меня кровь из глаз пошла...

Comment: Что за шуточки? Что с вашими глазами?  Доктора не нужно?

Comment: Специалиста по удалению воспоминаний, да.

Answer (score 1):

Просто, блин, те, кто пишут эти тексты к песням, часто вообще не заботятся ни о чём. Там, где я смотрел текст, я увидел вообще *гостинница* и *нафиг*! И никому не было интересно о смысле этой песни, пока Лео-мэтр не восстал, сказав: «*Веник* — это, что, богатство? Или Боярский совсем чокнулся-таки?»

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение и за веник-пфенниг)

Comment: Лео, немножечко исправил, в тексте было написано _нафиг_, а не _на фиг_ (слитно). :)

Comment: @Максим, а ответик бы...  Вы же были в теме, что думали про веник?)   Сомневались или нет?

Comment: Не сомневался. Просто смотрел в текст и думал: значит, _веник_ в песне был!

Comment: Вас трудно удивить) Но вы ведь песню не слушали, текст не смотрели? А произношение феник, о котором говорил Лео, его упорный интерес к этой теме вам  тоже не удивительны были?

Answer (score 1):

**Почему я думала, что это веник** (ответ после комментария Лео)

***Веник!** Какие могут быть сомнения! Но откуда там веник?*

*Все так считают — начальная установка **обозначена.** А это очень важный момент, теперь **с этой колеи не уйти**. Теперь я искренне верю, что там именно веник.*

*Но какой в этом  **смысл?**  Так это **символизм.**  Иной веник дороже пфеннига. **Раритетная вещь!**  Есть и этикетка с брендом. **Иностранный!** Отнесу в антикварный магазин, вот и деньги будут. Не получилось?  Не беда, в огороде закопаю, пусть в цене растет.  Так что с ним потом будет, **он же не вечный!** Так это тоже символизм, пусть **условно** хранится. Художественное воплощение идеи.*

*А дальше исторический **диалог** на тему: Ведь произносится ***феник***!! Так что с того? Рисуется актер,  **имидж у него такой**  — поиск новых форм, как без этого. **Веник это!***

*Может быть, мы **всегда** так поступаем? **Истину не ищем,** а находим удобное объяснение?*

Comment: Уж очень замысловато вы написали. Так пфениг, веник, феник или что-то еще? Песню не слушал. Лень!

Comment: У меня это художественный текст, не информационный. Особая композиция!  А лень – это плохо! Отсутствие любопытства к жизни...  Стоит задуматься.  У меня последнее предложение прочитайте и ответьте, пожалуйста: Может быть, мы всегда так поступаем? Истину не ищем, а находим удобное объяснение?  Поучительная история на примере песни, которую лень послушать.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Лень — это плохо. Я даже на вопросы не отвечаю из-за лени.

Comment: Просто вам надоело здесь, Серж. Я раньше меняла имидж раз в год, вот тогда интересно было.  А сейчас не получится. Но мудрые люди говорят, что нужно изменить отношение к предмету, то есть точку зрения в прямом смысле. Здесь можно развлечься, не так уж здесь плохо)

Comment: Так что у него? Стилизация? А веник — быть может аллюзия?

Comment: Совсем нет, это я так подумала. (А что другие думали, я и не знаю.  Некоторые вообще ничего не думали.) Борский произносит  пфенниг, имея в виду монетку.  А сейчас все думают, что это веник, и никого это не удивляет.